# useSWRMutation not passing payload correctly

Tags: mutation, swr, use-swr

I'm just incorporating swr, and when I use useSWRMutation, in the network section in the browser the payload is passed correctly but in the response section I get a 400 error saying that there are no values ​​to create the user
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3yoU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN4Gz.png)

I hope you can help me, I'm on the lookout.

Comment: Please update your question to include code for the problem